# Resize images in HTML using Python- how do I do it properly?

Tags: python, html, css

I have 10 images embedded in a wordpress post. I took the html so that I could replace whatever width they all have initially, with a width of 260px (and the height should be scaled accordingly). I also wanted to all align them to the right, wrapping text.

What I did was copy some html to a text file:

```
<img class="alignright wp-image-3087" src="https://wordpress-346062-1147012.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Signature-Design-By-Ashley-coffee-table-300x159.jpg" alt="Signature Design By Ashley coffee table" width="300" height="159" />
```

The goal width and height: 260 px, 138 px. I know it just takes basic math, so I already know how to scale the image. But my problem lies in changing the values of the `weight` and `height`. Is there a built-in module for storing and modifying img attributes?

I already came up with a script to search and replace, but it's fixed. What if I had widths of 800, or 1254? I know I can't just use some hard-coded detector for that.

```
with open("unedited_html") as u:
    listofu = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in u]
unedited_html_contents = listofu[0]

infile = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
outfile = "resized_image_%s"%(infile)

checkWords = (old_dimensions) #not yet established, because this is unpredictable
repWords = (new_dimensions) #260, and whatever the height is

f1 = open(infile)
f2 = open(outfile,"w+")
for line in f1:
    for check, rep in zip(checkWords, repWords):
        line = line.replace(check, rep)
    f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I used BeautifulSoup and re.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

infile = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
outfile = "resized_image_%s"%(infile)
outfile2 = 'resized_image_2_%s'%(infile)

f1 = open(infile)

for line in f1:
    if any(re.findall(r'<img', str(line), re.IGNORECASE)) == True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
        img = soup.img
        old_width = float(img['width'])
        old_height = float(img['height'])
        img['height'] = int(260*(old_height/old_width))
        img['width'] = 260
        with open(outfile,'a') as o:
            o.write(unicode(soup))
    else:
        with open(outfile,'a') as o:
            o.write(unicode(line))
f1.close()


f2 = open(outfile)
f3 = open(outfile2,"w+")
for line in f2:
    if any(re.findall(r'<img', str(line), re.IGNORECASE)) == True:
        y = re.sub(r'alignnone','alignright',line)
        f3.write(unicode(y))
    else:
        f3.write(unicode(line))
f2.close()
f3.close()
```